# How to fix messages_tab_disabled error in Slack's chat.postMessage API?

Tags: slack

I'm trying to post a direct message to a specific Slack user. I'm using `chat.postMethod` method. The below example works fine when `channel` is a channel ID. But when I change it to a users ID (as described in [this documentation](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#channels__post-to-a-direct-message-channel)), I get back a `messages_tab_disabled` error.

POST URL: https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage

```json
{
  "channel": "U02F7EXXXXX",
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "section",
      "text": {
        "type": "mrkdwn",
        "text": "Hello"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I get back...

```json
{
  "ok": false,
  "error": "messages_tab_disabled"
}
```

I can't find much on this other than a description on the documentation page that just says "Messages tab for the app is disabled.".

Where is it and how do I enable it?

Answer (score 12):

I stumbled upon how to fix this when I was poking around settings for my app. In case this helps anyone else in the future...

In your apps configuration page, under **Features** > **App Home**, scroll down to the **Show Tabs** section and there is an option called **Messages Tab** that is off by default. I turned it on and now I can message users directly.

Comment: One of those "I wish I could click 'this answer is useful' a dozen more times" answers!